# Login not remembered in Nancy.Authentication.Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nancy

Messing around with this problem on and off for the last couple of weeks but now I really need to fix it and I cant seem to get my head around it.

In short: I have a nancy app with Forms Authentication enabled. All works fine expect the sessions are not persisted between app restarts, so it seems. This should work because Forms Authentication uses cookies by default. Do you guys have any idea what might cause this behavior? Here's my code:

Bootstrapper.cs:

```
    protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines           pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);
            var formsAuthConfiguration = new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration()
            {
                RedirectUrl = "~/user/login",
                UserMapper = container.Resolve<IUserMapper>()
            };
            FormsAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, formsAuthConfiguration);
    }
```

and in the app startup:

```
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
        Nancy.Session.CookieBasedSessions.Enable(pipelines);
        //Nancy.Session.MemoryCacheBasedSessions.Enable(pipelines); <-- disabled just to be sure
        Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.RetainCasing = true;
        Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        StaticConfiguration.DisableErrorTraces = false;
        Elmahlogging.Enable(pipelines, "elmah");
        //Some background job initialization...
    }
```

the route in het module handling the login/POST request:

```
        Post["/login"] = parameters =>
        {
            VerifyUserViewModel userLoginData = this.Bind();
            var verified = userManager.VerifyAccount(userLoginData.Email, userLoginData.Password);
            userLoginData.LoginFailed = false;
            if (verified == false)
            {
                userLoginData.LoginFailed = true;
                return View["SignIn", userLoginData];
            }
            else
            {
                var user = userManager.GetByEmail((string)Request.Form.Email);
                DateTime? expiry = null;
                if (this.Request.Form.RememberMe.HasValue)
                {
                    expiry = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
                }
                return this.LoginAndRedirect(user.Guid, expiry, "/dash");
            }
        };
```

Finally, the IUserMapper implementation:

```
public class UserDatabase : IUserMapper
{
    private readonly IUserManager _userManager;
    public UserDatabase(IUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public Nancy.Security.IUserIdentity GetUserFromIdentifier(Guid identifier, Nancy.NancyContext context)
    {
        var user = (ReflectUser)_userManager.GetByGuid(identifier);
        var identity = new ReflectWebUser();
        identity.Map(user);
        return identity;
    }
}
```

You guys notice anything strange about my code that could hinder session persistence?

Please note that I am also using Token based auth in this app but I have disabled that completely for testing. Also, this problem was present before implementing Token auth.

Thanks!

Comment: Found the solution at the bottom of this page: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Forms-Authentication

Answer (score 6):

Incase the link dies.

The problem is Nancy generates a crypto key when the application is started, this means when you rebuild your app during development, and re-request the page, the cookie check will fail and be removed causing the user to appear unauthenticated.

The same would happen if IIS was recycled, the app would start again, generate a new key, bam users are logged out.

The solution is to generate a specific key yourself. When configuring Forms Auth you can create your own Crypto Config:

```
var cryptographyConfiguration = new CryptographyConfiguration(
    new RijndaelEncryptionProvider(new PassphraseKeyGenerator("SuperSecretPass", new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 })),
    new DefaultHmacProvider(new PassphraseKeyGenerator("UberSuperSecure", new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 })));

var config = 
    new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration()
    {
        CryptographyConfiguration = cryptographyConfiguration,
        RedirectUrl = "/login",
        UserMapper = container.Resolve<IUserMapper>(),
    };
```

This will persist logins during development and application recycles.